# Using functions with unclear parameters

Tags: c++, coding-style

I want to implement a `walk(x,y)` function that lets a sprite move up, down, left, or right exactly one unit. The gameboard is stored in an array where each tile is at the index `y*width+x`. So only knowing the current position, width and x and y, I can instantly calculate the new position (and check for obstacles or other stuff). This seems like a very nice solution to me but would this be bad code? Or is is alright in this case?

(A more readible solution would be to use `"direction"` as a parameter, but this would bloat the definition of the function itself, which may also lower performance)

Thx in advance!

Comment: You can use matrix.

Comment: The problem is not how I store the board. The problem is if using ```walk(x,y)``` would be  considered bad habit and if I should instead use ```walk("direction")``` even if this bloats the code for the function itself

Comment: The problem is that if you ask ten C++ developers whether "<X> would be considered bad habit", you will get eleven different answers.

Comment: Both solutions are fine. But walk("direction") gives user more information.

Comment: Alright, just wanted to make sure that I don't develop a really bad habit that might mess with me later on. TY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `walk(x, y)` function allows putting in more than 1 in distance, this case should also be implemented. Otherwise you would have to check for bad inputs. I would definitely say that it is a bad practice to write functions that are only partially implemented.

If you just want to move a single tile, there is a very elegant solution to this though:

```cpp
enum class Direction : unsigned {
    UP, RIGHT, DOWN, LEFT
};

constexpr int X[4] {
    0, 1, 0, -1
};
constexpr int Y[4] {
    1, 0, -1, 0
};

void move(Direction d) {
    int x = X[static_cast<size_t>(d)];
    int y = Y[static_cast<size_t>(d)];

    // move by x and y
}
```

The performance cost is near zero in this case. You're really worried unnecessarily. You can also use a single table instead of two separate ones:

```cpp
void move(Direction d) {
    int x = X[static_cast<size_t>(d)];
    int y = X[(static_cast<size_t>(d) + 1) & 0b11];

    // move by x and y
}
```

Comment: I'm not fully familiar with enum classes, but am I wrong if I assume that ```UP, RIGHT, DOWN, LEFT``` are automatically initialized to to the numbers ```0, 1, 2, 3```?

Comment: Yes, when no explicit value is given, enums start counting at 0. You can get the value of an enum by casting it to an integer type, such as `size_t` in this case.